# Laravel DataTable not displaying Show entries

Tags: jquery, datatables, laravel-7

I am using Laravel [DataTable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). My jQuery code is like below

```
    var id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

    var table = $('.nk-tb-item').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/product-details/'+ id,
            type: "GET"
        },
        ordering: false,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        pageLength: 5,
        columns: [
            {
                data: function(value){
                    var date = new Date(value.datetime);
                    return date.toLocaleDateString();
                },
                name: 'datetime'
            },
            {
                data: 'user_id',
                name: 'user_id'
            },
            {
                data: 'on_hand',
                name: 'on_hand'
            },
            {
                data: 'allocated',
                name: 'allocated'
            },
            {
                data: 'last_orderid',
                name: 'last_orderid'
            },
            {
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                searchable: false
            }
        ]
    });
```

But My Show entries is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pageLength: 5` option means you have chosen to display 5 rows per page.

By default, the [`lengthMenu`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) option (which controls the values in the drop-down) uses the following values:

```
[ 10, 25, 50, 100 ]
```

Your value (5) is not in that list - hence the drop-down cannot display any selected value. (But you should be able to see those other values if you click on the control.)

You can either change your pageLength to be one of those default values, or you can define a custom set of `lengthMenu` values - for example:

```
"lengthMenu": [ 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ]
```